# .gitignore after commit

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a git repository hosted on Github. After committing many files, I am realizing that I need to create `.gitignore` and exclude `.exe`, `.obj` files.

However, will it automatically remove these committed files from the repository? Is there any way to force that?

Comment: Future googlers may find this extremely useful. Succinct and to the point: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/ignore-tracked-files-in-git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: The correct answer [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241145/6501141https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241145/6501141). If you `git rm --cached` (or just delete the offending files and commit), it can delete those files on checkout. Using `git update-index --skip-worktree <files>` will remove them from being tracked directly.

Comment: I've just got it on GitHub Desktop by temporary moving the wrong-commited folders or files outside the local rep, modify correctly the .gitignore, `Ammend commits`, bring back inside the rep to its original location the folder and files moved, and push the commit.

Answer (score 415, accepted):

No you cannot force a file that is already committed in the repo to be removed just because it is added to the `.gitignore`

You have to `git rm --cached` to remove the files that you don't want in the repo. ( --cached since you probably want to keep the local copy but remove from the repo. ) So if you want to remove all the exe's from your repo do

```
git rm --cached /\*.exe
```

(Note that the asterisk * is quoted from the shell - this lets git, and not the shell, expand the pathnames of files and subdirectories)

Comment: @Madhur Ahuja Actually if you do `git rm /\*.exe` it will delete all exe's in your repo

Comment: What are the /\'s for?

Comment: @Costa they're there to escape the asterisk, to prevent the shell from interpreting it, as it is intended for `git`.

Comment: Warning: The files are kept in local, it's true... But other users running a `git pull` will see their files deleted.

Comment: Undo last commit is quite helpful in VS code, just wanted to mention that

Answer (score 97):

If you have not pushed the changes already:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m 'clear git cache'
git push
```

Answer (score 62):

> However, will it automatically remove these committed files from the repository?

No. Even with an existing `.gitignore` you are able to stage "ignored" files with the `-f` (force) flag. If they files are already commited, they don't get removed automatically.

```
git rm --cached path/to/ignored.exe
```

Comment: Does that mean i have remove individually each .exe

Comment: You are probably able to batch this, but I don't know how this works under windows

Answer (score 25):

I had to remove .idea and target folders and after reading all comments this worked for me:

```
git rm -r .idea
git rm -r target
git commit -m 'removed .idea folder'
```

and then push to master

Comment: `.idea` was my problem I guess it was yours too `:)`

Answer (score 5):

> However, will it automatically remove these committed files from the repository?

No.

The 'best' recipe to do this is using `git filter-branch` as written about here:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Removing-Objects

The man page for git-filter-branch contains comprehensive examples.

**Note** You'll be re-writing history. If you had published any revisions containing the accidentally added files, this could create trouble for users of those public branches. Inform them, or perhaps think about how badly you need to remove the files.

**Note** In the presence of tags, always use the `--tag-name-filter cat` option to `git filter-branch`. It never hurts and will save you the head-ache when you realize later taht you needed it

Comment: I ran this command it showed Rewrite 57c1f1f04a3ed01f50c3260714cfc82c973ac816 (3/3)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged and nothing happened

Comment: It is a warning, and most likely means that the master branch did not (yet) contain any revisions with the files to be removed. You can easily check that. If there is a problem, please update the question. **PS:** use -- `--all` to rewrite all (local) branches at once

Answer (score 2):

Even after you delete the file(s) and then commit, you will still have those files in history. To delete those, consider using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). It is an alternative to git-filter-branch.