# Does GitHub for Windows not notice if a .gitignore file is updated on the server?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github-for-windows

Here's my situation; our Unity project started without a Unity ready .gitignore file and the lead made a couple of initial commits before I cloned the repo. I fired up Unity and noticed it changed a bunch of meta files and other stuff with my own directories etc.

The lead added a Unity setup .gitignore that looks like this:

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
UnityProject/Temp/
UnityProject/Obj/
UnityProject/UnityGenerated/
UnityProject/Library/

# ===================================== #
# Visual Studio / MonoDevelop generated #
# ===================================== #
ExportedObj/
*.svd
*.userprefs
*.csproj
*.pidb
*.suo
*.sln
*.user
*.unityproj
*.booproj

# ============ #
# OS generated #
# ============ #
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
UnityProject/<project name>_0_0_0_1_Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll
UnityProject/<project name>_0_0_0_1_Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll
UnityProject/<project name>_0_0_0_1.exe
UnityProject/<project name>_0_0_0_1_Data/Mono/etc/mono/browscap.ini
UnityProject/<project name>_0_0_0_1_Data/Mono/etc/mono/2.0/machine.config
```

After syncing that commit, it seems to have had no effect on my local copy whatsoever. I've deleted my copy and re-cloned it and still, no results.

Here's a gif showing my frustration:
[image: GitHub frustration]
(Recorded just now, latest version of GitHub for windows)

Now, have I missed something here? I've looked over the documentation covering .gitignore files but I'm no closer to figuring out why this is happening and what I need to do to make my local copy ignore the files I specify.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535362/gitignore-after-commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Git will not delete files that are already checked into your repository.**

You need to actually remove the files now that they are added to your repository.

Use `git rm --cached path/to/ignored.file` to remove it from the repository but still keep it in your folder.