# git to ignore a hidden directory in the local repo

Tags: git

I just initialised a project directory to be a git local repo by doing `git init`

But `ls -la` shows that there is a hidden directory ".idea" which I think I don't need to track with my project.  If that is correct, I tried to add it to my .gitignore buy just appending a ".idea/*" at the end of that file.

`git status` still shows the .idea/ listed.

Reading other posts on SO did not help me much since they are trying to stop tracking files which are already being tracked, or on the remote repo.
I am trying to start a fresh and ignore .idea/ from the very beginning and on the local repo before pushing anything to the remote repo.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535362/gitignore-after-commit

Comment: You didn't exclude `.idea`, just all the files in it.  Use `.idea` instead in the `.gitignore` file.  That, at least, works for me, ignoring the directory and all the files therein.

Comment: @learnvst the question fred-j asked is not the same as the one you linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use git rm to remove the file in .idea folder from being tracked. What I usually do for my projects with Intellij IDEA, is like this :

```
git rm -r --cached .idea/
```

then

```
git add .
git commit -m "Excluded .idea from being tracked"
git push
```

From this moment on, the git won't track the idea folder any more.
You can also take a look at the answers for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535362/gitignore-after-commit)

Comment: (future / other readers) The "git add ." was a little weird for me.  But this answer got that pesky .idea/ folder removed that someone checked in.  Thanks.