# Git won't ignore files

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, gitignore

I have some log files that I want Git to ignore. They are all in:

```
/Lead Services/logs/
```

In the .getignore file, I have tried entering all of these:

```
/Lead Services/logs
/Lead Services/logs/
/Lead Services/logs/*
/Lead Services/logs/**
```

I've even tried to enter specific files:

```
/Lead Services/logs/LeadAcceptance-LocalDev.txt
```

No matter what I try, these files keep showing  up in Team Explorer under "Changes".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git rm` to exclude file from tracking permanently. In your local repository, do

```
git rm -r --cached logs/*
```

then

```
git add .
git commit -m "Excluded logs from tracking"
git push
```

From now on, the git won't track the logs folder, any more. [Also, you may refer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026376/git-to-ignore-a-hidden-directory-in-the-local-repo/35029533#35029533)