# in Git, once commited folder disappears on checkout

Tags: git, revert

I'm new to Git and here's my problem: I accidentally added to commit a folder with files essential to my project but unchanged (say, Downloaded/). I didn't track this folder before, it just stayed untouched from commit to commit. Now, after this last commit, when I make a checkout to some previous commit, the Downloaded/ folder disappears from a file manager.

What is the correct way to revert that change and bring the folder back? I don't want to track it, still, maybe I should?

I tried this:

```
git reset HEAD
```

and this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged Downloaded/
```

I can solve this 'manually', as I have a backup of the folder. Still, for learning reasons, I prefer to do it in git.

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think about ignoring such files, to avoid mistakes like this? 
https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

You should not have to think about, what files you are allowed to commit, this should be set up in the repo (e.g. using `.gitignore`, configs, whatever).

But as you said, maybe you should track them, but that's up to you.. Do those files belong to the repo/project? Should they be under version control?

For a temp directory (e.g. downloads?), I would just ignore it.

In your case, I would:

- add a `.gitignore` file
- and then remove those files from the repo using `git rm --cached <file>`

Actually that's pretty much, what you are looking for:
[gitignore after commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535362/gitignore-after-commit)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I thought about ignoring; now it's time to implement. Files I'm talking about are a part of the project but I don't need track them into git history as no change are made for them.

Comment: So that's some kind of local configs? But maybe then even "assume unchanged" can be an option. Should you get a "base version" of those files, when you do a fresh checkout/clone (e.g. when someone's new on the project)?

Comment: Yes, I should. These are additional scripts and the project won't work properly without them. Still, I can't bring the folder back to the previous versions of the project by assume-unchanged. (It was there before the last commit). Neither can I prevent the folder from adding to staging area after `--assume-unchanged` was run on it. I ran both `git update-index --assume-unchanged` and `git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged` from inside this folder and then `git add [folder name]` and `git status` and it's there!

Comment: Are those scripts the same for everyone? Then just, add them to the repo (without assuming or ignoring anything). If there's some machine/user specific configuration on them, I would not add them.

Comment: Well, they are already added. But when I checkout to some past commit (I sometimes need) they are eliminated...