# Git remove a file from a branch, keep it in the master

Tags: git

I create a new branch

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

then I delete a file from it

```
git rm --cached myfile.txt
```

but I want to keep it in the master; why when I checkout to the master

```
git checkout master
```

I get an "error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: file.txt" and if I force the checkout

```
git checkout master -f
```

the file is deleted from the file system?

I am sure I am missing something, but I just wanted to remove the file from a branch and not from the master while it seems that git wants to merge the branch when I checkout master.

The reason why I used `git rm`  and not `gitignore` was that the file was already been committed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to keep tracking `myfile.txt` on `master` but deleted from `mybranch`, then you simply need to delete it and commit the delete.

```
git checkout -b mybranch
rm myfile.txt
git commit -am "delete myfile.txt"
```

Now when you checkout `master`, you'll see your file returned and when you checkout `mybranch` it will be gone again.

Note that if you merge `mybranch` into `master`, it will be deleted on `master` then too.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I needed to add a "git add -u" before committing or use "git rm" instead of rm. If you edit your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Eugenio thanks for catching that! I edited my answer to use `git commit -am` which will add all changes, including removed files.

Comment: I can't believe this ans got 8 votes ... I think ques is ... if there is a way to restrict a file to master and not to other branches ... for example secret info can be kept in a property file in master branch and master branch will be accessible by admin only

Answer (score 7):

git will see the file as untracked because it is not committed yet. You have to commit the change before you switch branches.

So you created a branch and made changes to that branch. When you try to switch back to `master` git will disallow this, because there are changes that are not committed yet (or explicitly ignored; (that is actually what the `untracked` means)

The reason the file is restored when you force checkout (`git checkout -f master`)  `master` is because the file *is* in `master`

If you want to do this you will have to do the following

Create and check out branch

```
git checkout -b somebranch
```

Remove the file from `somebranch` (`--cached` will actually remove the file from the index, but will leave the file intact on your filesystem. See [git-rm reference docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm))

```
git rm --cached somefile
```

Commit the change

```
git commit -m "Remove somefile"
```

This will remove the file from git, but not from disk, so now to git you have an untracked change (somefile is on disk but not in git)

If you want other contributors to be able to checkout the branch, link it to a remote

```
git push --set-upstream origin somebranch
```

Now the file is removed from `origin/somebranch` and not `master`

When you add a file to `.gitignore` it is not removed from the repo if it is already committed. Changes to the file, howeve, will be ignored (so also deleting it). If you do that you still have to remove the file and commit. After that git will not track the file anymore when recreated (or any other action on the file).

Comment: This is exactly what I did, I commited before "checkout master". Files were not restored (which was what I expected, actually they were still in the filesystem before checking out), they have been DELETED from the filesystem after the checkout.

Comment: Don't use --cached. Just do 'git rm somefile' this will delete the file from your file system too. It should be restored when you checkout master again

Comment: 'git rm somefile' will actually do the same as 'git rm --cached somefile && rm somefile'. So only removing it from the index (cache) and leaving it on your file system is to git as if you added the file on disk but not to git). Hope clears somethings up

Comment: thanks for the comment; what is the purpose of --cached then?

Comment: In case you want to remove something from git but not from disk. 'rm somefile' will do the opposite.

Comment: yes so that is exactly what I wanted, removing the file from git (in that branch) but not from the disk, why was it wrong?

Comment: It is not wrong, but if you remove it from disk and not from git, but the file is in the git working tree and not ignored git will see it as a change.

Comment: sorry I still don't get it, you said "If you remove from the disk and not from git" but I did the opposite

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it is indeed "If you remove it from git, not from disk"

Comment: so there is no way to delete from git (but keep it in the filesystem) and then checkout to master?

Comment: If you mean you want to maintain the file, because it has changed compared to master, then you can remove the file from git using `--cached`. After that commit the change. Then stash your local changes using `git stash`, checkout to master and apply the stash with `git stash pop`

Comment: it has not changed, it's just that I don't want the file in a branch (in git, but preserving it in the file system) but I want to keep it in the master (both in git and in the file system).

Comment: Then you should ignore the file in your branch. That will prevent git from tracking the file.

Comment: as I said, I couldn't ignore it because was previously committed

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can't ignore the file"? If you do the following (assuming you have `somefile` in master

    1. `git checkout -b somebranch`
    2. `git rm --cached somefile`
    3. echo "somefile" >> .gitignore
    4. `git add .gitignore`
    5. `git commit -m "Remove somefile and stop tracking changes"`
    6. `git push --set-upstream origin somebranch`

This will create the branch, remove the file from git index and stop tracking the file in `somebranch` but still have the file on disk

Comment: However, doing a hard clean (`git clean -fdx`) or switching to `master` and then back to `somebranch` will remove the file from  disk (because it is not tracked in `somebranch` anymore.

Comment: What I meant is it was already committed (see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535362/gitignore-after-commit)

Comment: ✅ This is the answer that worked for my case. Thanks @Rik 

Answer (score 0):

Commit the change on mybranch before swapping back to master.