# Unable to ignore top-level folder and everything in it recursively

Tags: git, gitignore

I've committed a file in a folder previously and nothing I put in .gitignore is now ignoring the folder and everything in it. I've tried committing:

`.vscode`
`.vscode/`
`.vscode/*`
`.vscode/**`

Even with `/` at the beginning of each of those... .vscode and its contents keep showing up in `git status`.

If I commit `.vscode/settings.json` to .gitignore, the file keeps showing up in status whenever I make a change.

How am I supposed to get git to just start ignoring this folder and all of its contents?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6535362/1256452 - is this your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.gitignore will only ignore files that are untracked.  You would need to first remove the file from version control before git will ignore that path.

```
git rm -r --cached vcscode
git commit -am 'Untrack /vcscode'
```

At this point.. changes should not be tracked