# How to ignore .idea and .gradle files while commit to git

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I am try ignore the `.idea` and `.gradle` folders from android project while commit the code. I already added `.idea` and `.gradle` on the `.gitignore` file inside the app folder.

while run the command `git status`, It shows the files inside `.idea` and `.gradle` are showing in

*`Changes not staged for commit:`*

Here is my `.gitignore` file.

```
# idea files
.idea/

# Gradle files
.gradle/

/build
```

Answer (score 3):

To add already tracked file in gitignore you need to delete that file from cache. To delete from cache use this command

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Check [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) .

To remove folder from cache use

```
git rm -r --cached <folder>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you've already commited before making the .gitignore,
your .gitignore won't be taken into account for the file already commited.
follow this link for more info :
[.gitignore after commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535362/gitignore-after-commit)